# Multiple refrences to an element in an array vs assigning that element to a variable

Tags: c#, arrays, performance

If I make multiple refrences to the same element in an array is it better ,performance-wise, to just assign that element to a variable and refrence this variable instead? I am aware that this would make the code more readable and that is often more important, but looking strictly at the performance of the code - which way is better?

```
public Class Example
{
    public void ExampleOne()
    {
        //Assuming the values in the array are random.
        int[,] arr = new int[10,10];
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
            {
                if(arr[i, j] < 5 || (arr[i, j] > 10 && arr[i, j] < 20)) 
                {
                    arr[i, j] = 0;
                }
                else
                {
                    arr[i, j] = 1;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void ExampleTwo()
    {
        //Assuming the values in the array are random.
        int[,] arr = new int[10,10];
        int val;
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
            {
                val = arr[i, j];
                if(val < 5 || (val > 10 && val < 20)) 
                {
                    arr[i, j] = 0;
                }
                else
                {
                    arr[i, j] = 1;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've made a benchmark test on both your methods with different sizes of the array and.... if the elements of the array are less than around 640000, then second one is the fastest. Else, if the elements are more than around 640000 then the faster is the first one.

```cs
static void ExampleOne()
        {
            Stopwatch stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();

            //Assuming the values in the array are random.
            int[,] arr = new int[10, 10];
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
                {
                    if (arr[i, j] < 5 || (arr[i, j] > 10 && arr[i, j] < 20))
                    {
                        arr[i, j] = 0;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        arr[i, j] = 1;
                    }
                }
            }

            Console.WriteLine(stopwatch.ElapsedTicks);
            stopwatch.Stop();
        }

        static void ExampleTwo()
        {
            Stopwatch stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();

            //Assuming the values in the array are random.
            int[,] arr = new int[10, 10];
            int val;
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
                {
                    val = arr[i, j];
                    if (val < 5 || (val > 10 && val < 20))
                    {
                        arr[i, j] = 0;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        arr[i, j] = 1;
                    }
                }
            }

            Console.WriteLine(stopwatch.ElapsedTicks);
            stopwatch.Stop();
        }
```

Comment: Unfortunately I couldn't reproduce your results. I've tried doing the test on differently sized arrays to get a better average. For me, both methods take about the same amount of time (the 27 factor seems a bit high) but they were not consistent. For an 1000x1000 array it would take anywhere from 300000 to 400000 ticks and sometimes one methods was better than the other and sometimes it was the other way round.